# Qt Android: void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) --> Symbol: Class Task not found

Tags: java, android, firebase, qt

I am updating my qt android project to the latest firebase version. I cannot use the getToken function because the compiler doesn't find the "Task" class.

```
Symbol not found Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                                                ^
  Symbol: Class Task
```

What class do I have to import?
Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add import com.google.android.gms.tasks.*;